# Huge clear icon next to angular autocomplete input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm getting a huge clear button when I am using the angular md-autocomplete and not sure why.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Huge Clear Button]

I am creating an autocomplete using this fiddle: [md-autocomplete example](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1y1Lnkeh/5/)

my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>

<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem"
                 md-search-text="searchText"
                 md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)"
                 md-item-text="item.display"
                 md-min-length="0"
                 placeholder="Type something">
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>

    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>No matches found.</md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
<p>Test case type ca</p>
</div>
</div>
```

JS File:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);


// Main COntroller
app.controller('MainController', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.myDta = [{
        value: "apple",
        display: "apple"
    }, {
        value: "banana",
        display: "banana"
    }, {
        value: "gauva",
        display: "gauva"
    }, {
        value: "melon",
        display: "melon"
    }, {
        value: "potato",
        display: "potato"
    }, {
        value: "carrot",
        display: "carrot"
    }, {
        value: "cauliflower",
        display: "cauliflower"
    }, {
        value: "jasmine",
        display: "jasmine"
    }, {
        value: "cabbage",
        display: "cabbage"
    }, {
        value: "peas",
        display: "peas"
    }];


    $scope.getMatches = function (text) {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        var ret = $scope.myDta.filter(function (d) {
            return d.display.startsWith(text);
        });
        return ret;
    };

}]);

})();
```

in BundleConfig.cs (to load scripts):

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-touch.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-aria.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-material.js"));
```

The problem exists both in IE and Chrome.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Likely this is a css collision. Have you inspected the icon with developer tools to see what CSS property is setting it so large?

Comment: Are you loading angular-material.css?